# Duplicate Primary Key in EF Core when I try insert a new item in Children Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, mapping

When I go to insert a new record in the child table, it gives me an error saying that I cannot perform the action due to Primary Key problems, that is when I make the association with the parent object it tries to make the insert in the parent and it does not make any sense considering that the child object is referencing the parent and not the parent referencing the child.
Below is the code of my model and the mappings of the Entities:

DbContext Mapping

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<JackPot>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Entity<BetEntity>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserCode>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Beets).WithOne(c => c.Participant).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        builder.Entity<JackPot>().Property(x => x.Price).HasColumnType("smallmoney");       
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

JackPotModel

```
public class JackPot : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BetEntity> Bets { get; set; } = new List<BetEntity>();
    public JackPot(string name, string instructions, decimal price, string description, ApplicationUser owner)
    {
        Name = name;
        Owner = owner;
        Instructions = instructions;
        Price = price;
        Description = description;        
        UserId = owner.Id;
    }

    internal JackPot()
    {

    }
}
```

BetEntity

```
public class BetEntity : Entity
{
    public BetEntity(ApplicationUser participant, int beetPrice, string imageUrl) : base()
    {
        Participant = participant;
        BeetPrice = beetPrice;
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    internal BetEntity()
    {
        
    }
    public ApplicationUser Participant { get;private set; } = new ApplicationUser();
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int BeetPrice { get;private set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; private set; }
    public JackPot JackPot { get; set; } = new JackPot();
    public Guid JackPotId { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        
    }
    public ICollection<JackPot> JackPots { get; set; } = new List<JackPot>();
    public ICollection<BetEntity> Beets { get; set; } = new List<BetEntity>();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? ProfileUrl { get; set; }
    public string? Bio { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to do my insert using the code below:

```
 var aplicationUser = HttpContext.User.Claims.GetFromClaims();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(aplicationUser.Email ?? string.Empty);
            if (user is null)
            {
                return NotFound("Lamentablemente, no se ha encontrado ningún usuario con esa información. Por favor, verifica los datos ingresados o regístrate para crear una nueva cuenta.");
            }
            var jackPot = new JackPot(newJackPotViewModel.Name, newJackPotViewModel.Instructions, newJackPotViewModel.Price, newJackPotViewModel.Description, user);
            await _jackpotRepository.Add(jackPot);
```

I get the following exception in Cath:
`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (67bed5d8-2832-444e-b08f-0b1852e59289). The statement has been terminated.`

That is when I try to create a new JackSpot associating the logged in user to it Ef is trying to make a new insertion with the same Id in the Users Table which is wrong, because I just wanted the user to have the reference. I even apologize for this trivial error, but it's been a while since I've worked with EF, but as for this project it was the most viable choice I ended up choosing, usually I use NoSql databases or else RepoDB.

I would like when the insert is made in the JackPot table that the JackPot has a user reference.

Comment: In the new Jackpot call, try passing in the user.Id only and not the user object.

Comment: You need to make sure that the UserId property of your JackPot class matches an existing user Id in the AspNetUsers table, and that you are not creating a new user with the same Id as an existing one

Comment: @MRP So there you have it if you look at the example code I am using not only the same user but also the same user reference....

Comment: The basic problem is that `user` is not attached to the context in `_jackpotRepository`. But also, does EF know that `UserId` is the FK property belonging to `Owner`? As said above, it's better to just set `UserId`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The EF classes are POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects) classes, so they don't need to inherit from "Entity" class.
2. A good rule when create classes, is to define a property (whole name ends in "Id") of type "Int" to point out that property of type int will be the PRIMARY KEY.

So, if You have a property named "Id" (of type int) in your JackPot class (and also in the others), You don't need to write:

builder.Entity().HasKey(x => x.Id);

in your OnModelCreating method, because EF already knows which will be the Primary Key.

The same You should apply also on the Primary keys of the other classes.

Comment: OK... where does this answer the question? It's not that EF doesn't *know* the PK.

Answer (score 0):

My intention was to say that it is a good pratice to define an integer property like Primary Key (Microsoft says it, not Fabio Caruso). The PK so created will be clustered, unique and auto_increment, and You won't need to worry about anything else. For the other keys (FK): if You define an INT property named like Navigation Property Primary Key in every "child" class, the Foreign Key will be created in the correct way.

Here is my the code, fully functional and tested (I'm using Pomelo MySql)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EFCore_StackOverflow
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyContext db = new MyContext();

        db.Database.EnsureDeleted();  //Deletes the database
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();  //Creates it again

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Name = "FirstUser"
        };
        var added = db.ApplicationUsers.Add(user);
        int appId = added.Entity.AppUserId;

        JackPot jackPot = new JackPot()
        {
            Name = "FirstJackPot",
            Instructions = "Blablabla",
            Price = 1.000M,
            Description = "my money",
            AppUserId = appId   //Only the FK
        };
        
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JackPot> JackPots { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BetEntity> BetEntities { get; set; }
                    

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {               
            string connectionString = "Server = ...";            
            options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.JackPots).WithOne(c => c.Owner).HasForeignKey(c => c.AppUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Bets).WithOne(c => c.Participant).HasForeignKey(c => c.AppUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
            
            builder.Entity<JackPot>().HasMany(c => c.Bets).WithOne(c => c.JackPot).HasForeignKey(c => c.JackPotId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
            builder.Entity<JackPot>().Property(x => x.Price).HasColumnType("decimal");
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);         
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationUser
    {            
        [Key]
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }   //PK
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? ProfileUrl { get; set; }
        public string? Bio { get; set; }
        public ICollection<JackPot> JackPots { get; set; } = new List<JackPot>();
        public ICollection<BetEntity> Bets { get; set; } = new List<BetEntity>();            
    }
    public class JackPot 
    {
        public int JackPotId { get; set; }   //PK
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }   //FK
        public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }            
        public ICollection<BetEntity> Bets { get; set; } = new List<BetEntity>();            
    }

    public class BetEntity
    {                        
        public int BetEntityId { get; set; }   //PK            
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int BeetPrice { get; private set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; private set; }
        public int JackPotId { get; set; }   //FK
        public JackPot JackPot { get; set; } = new JackPot();
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }   //FK
        public ApplicationUser Participant { get; set; }
    }               
  }
}
```

So, if You want to insert a new Jackpot (like I do), the ApplicationUser property MUST BE NULL. Only its primary key (AppUserId) must be known and made explicit.
If the ApplicationUser property is not null, but You leave empty AppUserId property, A NEW APPLICATION USER will be created also.

In your case, searching an user and populating ApplicationUser property with ALL FIELDS FILLED (AppUserId also), has produced 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY error', BECAUSE THAT KEY ALREADY EXISTS.

Good luck.